# How can I plot an interaction in R when using a negative binomial model?

Tags: r, plot, regression

I'm new to R. I used a negative binomial model to test the effects of 2 variables (1 binary variable and 1 continuous variable) and a count response variable. I also added their interaction to the model.

Since the results from the `glm.nb` is minimal, I would like to plot the result somehow, especially the interaction.

I've done this to run the model:

```
Y<- cbind(N_Cooperations)
Model8 <- glm.nb(Y ~ Condition + NR + Condition*NR)
summary(Model8)

Call:
glm.nb(formula = Y ~ Condition + NR + Condition * NR, init.theta = 2.012332023, 
    link = log)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-2.2063  -0.9508  -0.1757   0.3389   2.5682  

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)   
(Intercept)    1.5379     0.6920   2.222  0.02626 * 
Condition     -2.9514     1.0876  -2.714  0.00665 **
NR            -0.1470     0.2065  -0.712  0.47654   
Condition:NR   0.7771     0.3170   2.451  0.01423 * 
---
```

Then I tried to use `plot(allEffects(Model8))` from the `effects` package to plot the interaction, but this is the message I received:

```
plot(allEffects(Model8))
Error in mod.matrix[, components] : subscript out of bounds
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In factor.cols & stranger.cols :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In (!factor.cols) & stranger.cols :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

What am I missing?

Again, I'm very new to R. Sorry in advance if this sounds silly.

Comment: Hi John, what package is `allEffects` from?

Comment: sorry, forgot to mention. it is from `Effects`.

Comment: What happens if you add the `data` argument to your model?

Comment: @Edward  When I do this `Model8 <- glm.nb(Y ~ Condition + NR + Condition*NR, data=naw_Data)` I get the same error.

Comment: Ok. Well, the `allEffects` function _does_ accept models of class "negbin" (you can try the example from the help page of glm.nb), so it must be your data. But since we are missing your data, it is difficult to know what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have some other variables in your environment that is throwing the error. It would be useful if you place all your variables into a data.frame. It works for me with an example dataset:

```
library(MASS)
library(effects)

set.seed(111)
df = data.frame(Y = rnbinom(100,mu=10,size=1),
NR = runif(100),Condition=rbinom(100,1,0.5))

fit = glm.nb(Y ~ Condition*NR,data=df)
```

The interaction term is specified using `:` and this `*` is used for factor crossing. See [help page](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/formula.html) if you are unclear. Below I can do the summary and we get a similar output to yours:

```
summary(fit)

Call:
glm.nb(formula = Y ~ Condition * NR, data = df, init.theta = 1.19503151, 
    link = log)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-2.3798  -1.0970  -0.2340   0.4323   2.0848  

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)    1.4744     0.2978   4.952 7.36e-07 ***
Condition      0.9414     0.3973   2.369   0.0178 *  
NR             1.0294     0.5003   2.058   0.0396 *  
Condition:NR  -0.9773     0.6809  -1.435   0.1512
```

Plotting it works:

```
plot(allEffects(fit))
```

[image]